# Why changing the frame of UISearchBar simply doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

```
CGRect rectSearchLocationFrame=self.rectsearchLocation;
CGRect rectSearchCityFrame = self.rectsearchCity;

rectSearchLocationFrame.size.width += change *changeByMuch;
rectSearchCityFrame.size.width -= change * changeByMuch;
rectSearchCityFrame.origin.x +=change*changeByMuch;
self.searchLocation.frame = rectSearchLocationFrame;
self.searchCity.frame = rectSearchCityFrame;

PO1(self.searchLocation.textField);
PO1(self.searchCity.textField);
//NSAssert(false, @"Hello");
```

I look carefully. self.searchLocation has indeed change frame

```
(lldb) po self.searchLocation
<BGSearchBar: 0x158e5130; baseClass = UISearchBar; frame = (0 38; 260 44); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x158d1ba0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x158e5220>>
```

You see, the frame? The width is 260 there, not 160. It shouldn't end in the middle.

Yet, this is the screenshot

[image]

If I animate the movement, it seems that it actually change size. However, it slowly goes back. Something make it goes back to it's original size.

I got this error:

> invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a
>   library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby
>   contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and
>   reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It
>   will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: are you using auto layout in your  nibs? try self.searchbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO if so.

Comment: Try to log `rectSearchLocationFrame` instead of the view frame. Note that the `frame` property is animated, so it doesn't have to show the current size shortly after change.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];   

<duration of animation>
<change frame of your search bar>

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or

```
[UIView
     animateWithDuration:0.1
     animations:^{

         <change frame of your search bar>

     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished) {


     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) setActiveSearchBar:(BGSearchBar *)activeSearchBar
{

    _activeSearchBar=activeSearchBar;
    AssertMainThread
    if (activeSearchBar==self.searchLocation)
    {
        [self vChangeFrameBy:1];
    }
    else if (activeSearchBar==self.searchCity)
    {
        [self vChangeFrameBy:-1];
    }
    else if (activeSearchBar==self.searchBusiness)
    {
        [self vChangeFrameBy:0];
    }
}
```

I made a stupid bug

Look at the code above. There is an extra ; on the original code after the last else if

So the last else if was like this:

```
    else if (activeSearchBar==self.searchBusiness);
    {
        [self vChangeFrameBy:0];
    }
```

Which mean [self vChangeFrameBy:0]; is always called no matter what :(